# Как отцентрировать изображения Owl Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, карусель

Есть карусель с изображениями различного размера. Как их отцентрировать внутри карусели? У меня не получается...

UPD. Отцентрировать и по вертикали, и по горизонтали.

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/524/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css');

#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px;
  display: table;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/250x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/150x150/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: отцентрировать как? По вертикали? Горизонтали? Или то и то

Comment: @ThisMan отцентрировать - и то, и то

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164738/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Owl Carousel создаёт дополнительные блоки внутри вашей вёрстки. Поэтому, чтобы правильно добавить CSS
   свойства, надо работать вот с такой структурой:

   ```html
   <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
       <div class="owl-wrapper">
         <div class="owl-item">
           <div>
             <img src="" alt="">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item">
           <div>
             <img src="" alt="">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   То есть, таблицей делаем `.owl-wrapper`, а ячейками — `.owl-item`.
2. И на все элементы карусель навешивает атрибут `style`. Например, у блока с классом `.owl-wrapper` там прописывается `display: block;`. Поэтому в своих стилях приходится добавить `!important`.
3. Чтобы сработало вертикальное центрирование по ячейкам таблицы, нужно перебить им свойство `float`.
4. Ну а для горизонтального центрирования достаточно `text-align: center;`.

Приятно, что в этом решении высота карусели не скачет, когда самая высокая картинка уезжает за пределы экрана. Проверьте результат:

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/yqfwzkL0/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css');

#owl-demo .owl-wrapper {
  display: table !important;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  text-align: center;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/250x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/150x150/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/autoHeight.html
Попробуй так

свои стили что сейчас можешь убрать а использовать только

```
#owl-demo .owl-item img{
   display: block;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: нет, у меня, если вы заметили количество item в слайдере больше, чем 1